# How to load 3D LUTs on Dslr?

Tags: camera, effects, dslr, filter

There are few film emulation LUTs ([LookUp Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table#Lookup_tables_in_image_processing)) that I would like to use on my DSLR in real-time (live) because shooting live with LUT applied gives very accurate results and cuts down time on post editing process.

I would like to know if there are any ways to use LUTs live on DSLR just like you can with some smartphone apps.

Comment: In general, it is preferable to pick one site or another to post a question on, based on where you feel it fits best.  Posting the same question on multiple sites divides up answers and makes it harder for someone else to find answers in the future.  Cross post is http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/86088/how-to-load-3dlut-on-dslr%3E

Comment: @AJHenderson Well its person named null who recommended me to ask here http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/86088/how-to-load-3dlut-on-dslr#comment150122_86088

Comment: yes, he was probably correct that this is the "better fit".  In those cases, the best practice if you already have answers is to flag the question for moderator attention and ask them to migrate.  Then the entire question can be moved with existing answers.  It isn't a big deal either way, just was letting you know the general guideline for it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there are no dslrs with lut loading capabilities. Further, many professional grade cameras don't even have that ability.

I suggest getting a small HD monitor and loading it there and connecting that to your Dslr.